# PDO query with multiple like

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is this safe in terms of preventing SQL injection?

```
$query = "select * from products where 1";
$searchterms = @preg_split("/[ ,]+/",trim($_REQUEST["textsearch"]));
foreach ($searchterms as &$st) {
    $query .= " and description like ?";
    $st = "%".$st."%";
}
$statement = $dbh->prepare($query);
$statement->execute($searchterms);
```

I usually do it with `bindParam()` but this seems so much simpler, it's suspicious.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try at Code Review, didn't even know that existed. Jay I don't know, why do binds in the for loop? Doesn't this work the same?

Comment: Why are you using `@` like that to suppress errors?

Comment: Just to keep it short, in my code I check if `isset($_REQUEST["textsearch"]))` and initialize the array beforehand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's safe. This does exactly the same thing as `bindParam()` from MySQL's point of view.

The reason to use `bindParam()` is that you want to bind variables by reference. Other than that, the only thing `bindParam()` does is make you write a more PHP code for no reason.

PS: Tangential to your question, but using `LIKE` for full text search is bound to be terribly slow. You should use a real full text index or else Sphinx Search. See my presentation [Full Text Search Throwdown](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql).

Comment: Damn, always something new to learn. :) This particular database is unlikely to have more than 1000 products or so, but still... why be sloppy?

Comment: Wow 7 seconds vs 0.2 seconds (fulltext MyISAM)? I'm sold.